# Is there a musical term for a fading or decaying echo?

Tags: terminology, guitar-effects, effects

Is there a term for a fading echo of a note or chord?
And how might someone create this effect in a modern DAW based on recording a single note or chord on a keyboard or guitar?

I've done a search and can't find any info on this.

I hear this effect best at 5:36 (and beyond) in this song. I think a keyboard is being played.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That’s just a delay effect

Comment: In the terminology of synths and guitar effects, "decay" can be a useful word for getting progressively softer

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Todd. It's explained at 4:52 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jVkui7DAEI

Comment: There is not really a musical term for it because it is an effect created with technology.